Parse CSV from Request Body (Array Buffer)
I'm trying to make a REST API that allowes users to Upload a CSV in Order to write the data into a Database.
However, I seem to be having issues going from ArrayBuffer to readable lines.
I'm running a Google Cloud Function that uses Express. I'm running my function locally and I've tried parsing the File via the Body either as form-data or directly as binary in the body (via Postman).
import csv from'csv-parser';
import multer from 'multer'
import fs from 'fs'

const storage = multer.memoryStorage();
const upload = multer({ storage: storage });

app.post("/upload", upload.single('csvFile'), async(req, res) => {
    
    const buffer = new Uint8Array(req.body)

    fs.createReadStream(buffer)
        .pipe(csv())
        .on('data', (row) => {
            console.log(row);
        })
        .on('end', () => {
            res.send('File uploaded and processed successfully');
        });
})

This is the furthest I've gotten. However fs seems to be trying to open the File as it throws the Error ENAMETOOLONG and enteres the entire data.

fs.createReadStream is designed to work with file paths, not in-memory data

Hi, Has the below answer met your requirement ?

There are two points to convey:

The memory storage engine stores the files in memory as Buffer objects.
This buffer is accessible to the code by req object as req.file.buffer.

In order to create a Readable Stream from the buffer, Readable.from may be used.


The revised code and the test input and results are enclosed below.
server.mjs
import csv from 'csv-parser';
import multer from 'multer';
import express from 'express';
import { Readable } from 'stream';

const app = express();
const storage = multer.memoryStorage();
const upload = multer({ storage: storage });

app.post('/upload', upload.single('csvFile'), async (req, res) => {

  Readable.from(req.file.buffer)
    .pipe(csv())
    .on('data', (row) => {
      console.log(row);
    })
    .on('end', () => {
      res.send('File uploaded and processed successfully');
    });
});

app.listen(3000, () => {
  console.log('L@3000');
});

Client.js
const fs = require('fs');
const axios = require('axios');
const FormData = require('form-data');

const formdata = new FormData();

formdata.append('csvFile', fs.createReadStream('./sample.csv'));

axios
  .post('http://localhost:3000/upload', formdata)
  .then((data) => {
    console.log(data.data);
  })
  .catch((error) => {
    console.log(error);
  });

sample.csv
product,qty,unit,price,currency
product-1,100,KG,12,Rs
product-2,50,KG,200,Rs
product-3,600,KG,14,Rs
product-4,700,KG,32,Rs

Testing with the client:
Request: node client

Response : File uploaded and processed successfully

Server console output:

{
  product: 'product-1',
  qty: '100',
  unit: 'KG',
  price: '12',
  currency: 'Rs'
}
{
  product: 'product-2',
  qty: '50',
  unit: 'KG',
  price: '200',
  currency: 'Rs'
}
{
  product: 'product-3',
  qty: '600',
  unit: 'KG',
  price: '14',
  currency: 'Rs'
}
{
  product: 'product-4',
  qty: '700',
  unit: 'KG',
  price: '32',
  currency: 'Rs'
}

Citations:

Converting a Buffer into a ReadableStream in Node.js

Multer - Section MemoryStorage


